# Vertical menu with left image

Tags: css, navigation

I have a two part problem on [my site](http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/?page_id=23)

I want the navigation menu to look something like the attached image:

[image: Side Navigation Menu Example]

The first problem I have is making the nav menu show up off of the right side of the page. I think I have the margins set right but the menu doesn't appear after it hits the right side of the yellow border.

Second is the little banner that goes behind the site body on the left side. I created an image for this but when I try to place it, it won't show up in the right place. Right now I have it set to repeat so you can see where it is at (along with some funky positioning). Is there a way to make the part that shows below the actual menu link to show up?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this affect using pure css.

**HTML**

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58" id="menu-item-58">
    <a href="http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/?page_id=57">Building Facts</a>
    <div>
       <div class="wrap-behind"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
#extra-navbar .menu-item {
    margin-bottom: 0.9rem;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.wrap-behind {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F9B233;
    border-left: 13px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid #053053;
    border-top: 10px solid #053053;
    float: left;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

#extra-navbar ul li {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #104571;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: That would be great but I am using WordPress and my menu is generated dynamically. Would you know where to edit the HTML code in the WordPress files for Custom Menus?

Comment: Got it, works great! Just had to install Advanced Menu Widget and put <div><div class='wrap-behind'></div></div> in the area of the Widget that says After the Link.

Answer (score 0):

div #page has class .site with rule `overflow: hidden;` it cause the first problem

Comment: Kevin Bowersox gave solution) You cannot use background-image for this purpose because this triangle is not within element. so u got to use another element with bg of this triangle.

Answer (score 0):

In style.css on line 1431 you have the property `overflow: hidden`. Remove that and you will see the stuff to left of the menu. That should help both your problems.

Comment: That helped with getting the menu to show all the way to the left but how about getting the little image to show up on the left side underneath the <li> section of the nav. I can change the position from bottom to top but it won't show up below (overflowing).